# Google PageSpeed shows 'Use HTTP/2' as oportunity, don't understand why

Tags: http, https, pagespeed

I'm trying to optimize the speed of website, and when I run a test through PageSpeed I get "Use HTTP/2" as a recommendation. It shows like all assets are delivered through HTTP protocol.

When I check page source this is not the case. There is no mixed content on page. Everything is delivered through HTTPS.

Did someone have a similar experience?

Here is the link to Google Page Speed report:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fav-candy.co.uk%2F&tab=desktop

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/2 is a new version of the HTTP and HTTPS protocol.

All browsers support it, and if you upgrade your server to support it too you likely get much better performance.

Even after you upgrade, your urls still start with `https://`. The change is invisible/transparent to the user after you set this up. After the switch, every client will be a little faster.

Comment: I got feedback from support that HTTP/2 is supported by server, and even when I test it I get positive result - HTTP/2 is supported (https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test). Can it be problem with something else?

Comment: @dejan you are right, i see http/2 on your server. I don't know why pagespeed thinks some of it isn't... strange. Do you have more than 1 server?

Comment: Thanks on reply. No, I don't have cluster. It is standard set up. Not really sure what is next step for me. It looks like some kind of misconfiguration.